# how find method in class

Tags: php, function

I need check method collector.  I run a function collector(); and it runs. But I don't visible this function.

```
class Query {


    public function Ands ($ands) {
       ...
    }

    public function __call($str, $by) {

    }

    public function ors($ors) {
        .....
    }

    public function like($like) {
    ....
    }

    public function eq($eq) {
    ...
    }

    public function notEq($neq) {
    ...
    }
}
```

this my class

Comment: [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.method-exists.php) combine with [`is_callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) to ensure it's actually callable.

Comment: yes, i don't found the function collector

Answer (score 0):

When a method that doesn't exist is called on an object, PHP will fall back to the `__call` method, if it's defined in the class. The definition of this function must be:

```
public mixed __call ( string $name , array $arguments );
```

`$name` will be the name of the function that was called (in this case, `collector`), and `$arguments` will be an array of the arguments provided to it, in order. This is often used to provide "dynamic" method definitions, based on the current properties of a given instance.

This is documented here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying how to call the function if it is named collector

```
public function __call(string $name, array $args)
{
    if($name === 'collector'){
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

You can only get the function name here and perform a specific task for the given name but if you want to call the function in another class then you have to instantiate the class and call the method on or you can use any other method like call_user_method_array()...